# How to Insert duplicate rows in SQL Server table from excel?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an Excel sheet with the following columns:

```
[API], [BasePrice], [CREATIONDATE], [CREATIONDATETIME], 
[DealerCode], [DealerName], [InvoiceNor], [MRP], [MaterialNumber]
```

I have to insert the data from these columns into a SQL Server table with the same column structure.

The challenge is: `[InvoiceNor]` and `[MaterialNumber]` are the columns that should be unique key in the table (`order`), but the data in Excel in these columns has duplicate rows and the columns `[BasePrice]`, `[MRP]` in the same rows contain unique values.

How can I insert the data from Excel into a SQL Server table or suggest me the structure of the table?

Current Table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order]
(
[API] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[BasePrice] [float] NULL,
[CREATIONDATE] [datetime] NULL,
[CREATIONDATETIME] [datetime] NULL,
[DealerCode] [float] NULL,
[DealerName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[InvoiceNor] [float] NOT NULL,
[MRP] [float] NULL,
[MaterialNumber] [float] NOT NULL,
constraint uk_InvoiceNor_MaterialNumber UNIQUE (InvoiceNor 
asc,MaterialNumber asc)
 )
```

Comment: So what should happen with multiple Excel rows that have identical `(InvoiceNor, MaterialNumber)` combinations? What is your resolution strategy for this case?

Comment: describe table order

Comment: Identicle (InvoiceNor, MaterialNumber) should be inserted but not understanding what to do with duplicate (InvoiceNor, MaterialNumber) and unique [BasePrice], [MRP] in the same row

Comment: You are the one that needs to decide what to do with them. Add them up? Pick the first one? This is not a question that we can answer. You need to find out what you should do with these duplicates.

Comment: Actually I am asking the way if without deleting that duplicates i can manage the table data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot insert those unless

- you remove the unique keys constraint, or
- create a new table (ID Pk, InvoiceNor, MaterialNumber). Remove
  InvoiceNor, MaterialNumber from your table and add ID Pk as a foreign
  key